# How do you change the primary colour on a resource basis in react-admin?

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I have various resource components that sit inside the react-admin Admin component. The admin component has a custom layout. Each of the resource screens has a different primary colour though, to represent the section that you are in and the content type. How is it possible to  pass a specific theme object variable of primary colour to each resource that is in then used inside my custom Layout?

```
  <Admin
authProvider={AuthProvider}
dashboard={Dashboard}
dataProvider={graphQLProvider}
history={history}
layout={Layout}
title="Home"
```

> 

```
  <Resource name="User" options={{label: 'Administrators'}} list={UserList} show={UserShow} edit={UserEdit}
            create={UserCreate} icon={UserIcon}/>
```

Should I be using the className prop which is available on 'every react-admin component' or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-admin doesn't support this feature, but you can achieve it using a custom layout (see [Replacing the appbar](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#replacing-the-appbar)) and a listener on the history location to get the resource from the URL. Something like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppBar } from 'react-admin';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
   posts: {
       backgroundColor: 'red',
   },
   comments: {
       backgroundColor: 'blue',
   }
});

const MyAppBar = ({ children }) => {
   const [resource, setResource] = useState();
   const history = useHistory();
   const classes = useStyles();
   useEffect(() => {
      const newResource = extractResourceFromPathname(history.location.pathname); // left as an exercise to the reader
      if (newResource !== resource) {
          setResource(newResource);
      }
   }, [history.location.pathname]);

   return <AppBar className={classes[resource]} {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Although, as I progess and try and add the primary colour to various parts of the layout it is becoming more problematic. How would I pass the colour from the theme directly into the makeStyles method instead, so that I can sprinkle that colour wherever?

Comment: makeStyles accepts a function as argument, which receives the theme. That way you can set styles depending on the theme. Check e.g. this component from the material-ui source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3ab4356063cfcca29277f3703635c850f918d56a/docs/src/pages/components/progress/CustomizedProgressBars.js#L21-L37

Comment: Thanks - I did something similar. I modified the above answer to have an array of potential themes with the resourceName as the name of each element and then in the layout page I match up the history pathName with the theme array element. That way I don't need to modify the makeStyles classes at all as I have the correct individual resource theme instead.